prestashop 8.1.7 module hook being fired more than once
I have this module that contains a hook that reduces the product price by 2 and i have for example a product original price is 22 and becomes 16 also tried some echos and it echos twice so i assumed it gets fired twice
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class HalvePriceOutOfStock extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'halvepriceoutofstock';
        $this->tab = 'pricing_promotion';
        $this->version = '0.1.0';
        $this->author = 'Ali Fertah';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Halve Price for Out-of-Stock Products');
        $this->description = $this->l('Displays out-of-stock products with half the original price.');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('displayProductPriceBlock');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }

    public function hookDisplayProductPriceBlock($params)
    {
        $params['product']['price'] = $this->updateProductPrice($params);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'product_price' => $params['product']['price']
        ));
    }

    public function updateProductPrice($params)
    {
        $product = $params['product'];
        $rawPrice = trim($product['price']);
        if ($product['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $cleanedPrice = preg_replace('/[^\d,.]/', '', $rawPrice);

            if (strpos($cleanedPrice, ',') !== false && strpos($cleanedPrice, '.') === false) {
                $cleanedPrice = str_replace(',', '.', $cleanedPrice); 
            } elseif (strpos($cleanedPrice, ',') !== false && strpos($cleanedPrice, '.') !== false) {
                $cleanedPrice = str_replace(',', '', $cleanedPrice); 
            }

            $priceFloat = (float)$cleanedPrice;
            $priceFloat = $priceFloat - 2;
            $formattedPrice = number_format($priceFloat, 2, '.', '');

            return $formattedPrice;
        } else {
            return $rawPrice;
        }
    }
}


I tried to do a variable that checks if it gots executed or not but it doesnt execute for the rest of the products

The hook you are currently using is only for displaying the price, it will not do anything regarding the price.
Try it with this hook: actionProductPriceCalculation
